# Making Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity compatible with Microsoft.AspNet.Identity Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I have a existing MVC web application that makes use of the **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity** for user management. Now I am trying to build a Progressive Web App (PWA) and from what I read on the internet is going with .Net Core is the right approach and already there are Nuget Packages like  [WebEssentials.AspNetCore.PWA](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials.AspNetCore.ServiceWorker) which makes life easier to build PWA. But the problem I am running into is that the Identity for .Net core ( **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity**) has some changes in the Identity models compared to the previous version. I want to be able to **reuse the existing database** which is built using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity in MVC project.

I did try Installing the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity packages to the .Net Core project but I get warnings like:

> Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.2.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Is there any solution to make the Core identity compatible with existing database? Keeping into account the Account Controller functionality does not break.

Basically I need to get the Core App in sync with MVC. What suggestions do you have?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you able resolve your issue. Currently, I'm working on the same issue. If you can share your experience it would be great.

Comment: @Sampath Unfortunately I was not able to resolve this issue. It was more complicated than I thought and also making changes in inbuilt stuff would introduce bugs. So I rather quit this approach (.Net core) and I built my PWA using MVC itself. Are you trying to build a PWA too ?

Comment: I am trying to revamp my system to IdentityServer4, .net Core web API. I need this change for the Identity server 4.

Comment: @Sampath, Did you have any luck with that? I have exactly the same issue as you!

Comment: @RomanBorovets Yes, I was able to migrate the existing DB. Steps and scripts can be found from the below links.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343512/migrate-existing-microsoft-aspnet-identity-db-ef-6-to-microsoft-aspnetcore-ide        
       https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/6425