# Migrate existing Microsoft.AspNet.Identity DB (EF 6) to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity (EF Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I am working on an application (ASP.NET MVC) which uses **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity**. Now I want to revamp my application to ASP.NET Core which uses **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity**. But those two has some differences in each model. Is there any direct way to generate initial migration for **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identit**y related changes in-order to connect existing DB with ASP.NET Core identity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to migrate existing DBs using the following steps.

1. Create a new ASP.net Core project and modify it's `ModelSnapshot` to match with EF6. After that, you can generate a script for the changes of EF6 to EF Core.
2. Write a script to update the AspNetUsers table. In ASP.net core identity when authenticating it is used `NormalizedEmail`, `NormalizedUserName` columns. So we need to update those two columns using our existing data.

Hope this helps someone out there...

Please follow up [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/6425) GitHub thread for more information.

Answer (score 3):

I converted a 'full' Identity Database to Core Identity.  My situation may not be a perfect fit for yours.  I am *not* using EF Migrations.  I only use the Users and Roles features. I used these steps:

- Copy the database
- Drop the Identity related tables AND the MigrationHistory...

  - drop table IF EXISTS AspNetRoleClaims
  - drop table IF EXISTS AspNetUserTokens
  - drop table IF EXISTS AspNetUserClaims
  - drop table IF EXISTS AspNetUserRoles
  - drop table IF EXISTS AspNetUserLogins
  - drop table IF EXISTS AspNetUserClaims
  - drop table IF EXISTS AspNetRoles
  - drop table IF EXISTS AspNetUsers
  - drop table IF EXISTS __EFMigrationsHistory

Allow the Identity Core migration to run, creating the new tables that Core Identity prefers

Copy identity data from the Old Database

--Copy over users data

```
insert into AspNetUsers(Id, UserName, NormalizedUserName, Email, NormalizedEmail,
    EmailConfirmed, PasswordHash, PhoneNumberConfirmed, TwoFactorEnabled, LockoutEnabled, AccessFailedCount
    )
    select Id, UserName, UPPER(UserName), Email, UPPER(Email), 
    1, PasswordHash, 0, 0, 0, 0 from [OldDatabase].dbo.AspNetUsers
```

--Copy over Roles

```
insert into AspNetRoles(Id, [Name], NormalizedName)
     select Id, [Name], UPPER([Name]) from [OldDatabase].dbo.AspNetRoles
```

--copy over user/roles

```
insert into AspNetUserRoles select * from [OldDatabase].dbo.AspNetUserRoles
```

I don't use any of the other tables.  I left them empty.

Answer (score 2):

There is a thorough [explanation](https://medium.com/@goodealsnow/asp-net-core-identity-3-0-6018fc151b4) here regarding asp.net core 3.0 and how to migrate your db into an asp.net core identity 3.0 db.

Read it through and I hope it will help anyone who comes across it.