# Sharing .Net Identity between .Net Core 5.0 and .Net Framework 4.6.1 project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

What is the best way to deal with multiple projects that need to share the same user Identity repository?

For example, we have a couple of 4.6.1 Framework Web projects (one is an OAuth 2.0 API project and another ASP/MVC/Razor reporting project), both share the same (AspNetXXX) Identity tables in a SQL database and these are filled with our client's credentials.

We are embarking on a new project that will implement GraphGL via ChilliCream/HotChocolate and therefore, we felt it was probably best to start it as a .Net Core 5.0 project, as we would like it to have some longevity. When creating the project, we chose the 'Individual Accounts' Authentication type option, which adds Identity to the project.

It was a long shot, hoping that the three projects would be able to coexist - as we expected the .Net core implementation of Identity to no longer be backwards compatible with the 4.6.1 projects. We found that any user that logged on to the .Net Core project, could then no longer sign in to the older projects as the Password Hash field on their account had been updated as part of the sign in.

One option would be to update the older projects to .Net Core, but we don't have the time to do this currently.

So... (sorry for the long question) is there a better way for users to be able to authenticate against all three apps?

Comment: You can look into [Migrate existing Microsoft.AspNet.Identity DB (EF 6) to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity (EF Core)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343512/migrate-existing-microsoft-aspnet-identity-db-ef-6-to-microsoft-aspnetcore-ide). Anyway, looks like the only known way for this is making a migration, and there are no solutions to make this database backwards compatible

Comment: I've done something similar previously by creating a custom password hasher for a .Net Core project to make it so existing users could login in to the .Net Core app using the existing database. This made sure that updating passwords didn't prevent logging in to the older .Net Framework app too. Will add more if I can remember more.

Comment: We use a .Net Standard project that targets both Core 3.1 and .Net 4.8. The .Net projects use EF 6 and the Core projects use EF Core. All apps point to the same db. The downside, at times we have to update two model builders.